# How to select an element from a string value

Tags: jquery

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PSV4F/) code :

```
<div id="example">
    Hello
</div>

var string="example";
alert($(''+string).html());
```

but it should print "Hello" not null...why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
alert($('#'+string).html());
```